# "Failed to fetch" while updating

Tags: apt, software-sources

I'm trying to update from Ubuntu 12.10 lately but I keep getting the "Failed to fetch" error.

```
W: Failed to fetch
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/Release 
Unable to find expected entry 'independent/binary-amd64/Packages' in
Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release  Unable to find
expected entry 'independent/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong
sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/Release  Unable
to find expected entry 'independent/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release
file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/Release 
Unable to find expected entry 'independent/binary-amd64/Packages' in
Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I changed the server and deleted the source lists from `/var/lib/apt/lists/` like some answers say but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message

> (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

Means that either some entry in your `sources.list` file is wrong or a line is malformed.

Searched the Web and I found this [old bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/947296), it is not exactly old, but *Expired*.

The solution (workaround is better word) is to examine your `sources.list` file and remove the word **independent** from the lines. Try it.

A good and detailed command to see **all** your `sources.list` entries is bellow:

```
find /etc/apt -name '*.list' -exec bash -c 'echo -e "\n$1\n"; cat -n "$1"' _ '{}' \;
```

Comment: Works like a charme! thanks alot. I found tone of updates waiting and I can install softwares now :) I found that bug too. Almost lost hope on Ubuntu there.

Comment: In this case you need to search and remove `independent` as that appears in the error message (`Unable to find expected entry 'independent/...`). If someone else has a different error - e.g.  (Unable to find expected entry 'xyx') - you need to examine the file and remove `xyz`.

Answer (score 3):

If you land here in 2019 because apt update is spitting out something like this:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://mariadb.biz.net.id/repo/10.2/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not connect to mariadb.biz.net.id:80 (203.142.69.189), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

This worked for me:

- sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
- **Comment out:** deb [arch=amd64] http://mariadb.biz.net.id/repo/10.2/ubuntu bionic main
- **Add:** deb [arch=amd64] http://nyc2.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu bionic main

You can change the mirror. I like digitalocean but this can be any valid mirror.

- sudo apt update

Problem solved for me.

Comment: `deb [arch=amd64] http://mirror.netcologne.de/mariadb//mariadb-10.4.8/repo/ubuntu/ trusty main` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming to this in the future for a newer version of Ubuntu, NikTh's answer works but you want to search for **commercial** instead of **independent**.

This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I changed the server name by testing the best server in the software & updates application and then did a sudo apt-get update. Worked like a charm.