# Updating Problem

Tags: updates

Let me thank you in advance for reading and attempting to help me.
Thank you!
Sorry for the terrible editing
also had to change some of the links cuz im not reputable :)

My problem is as such:
Opening Update software center an error window appears saying:
"Items cannot be installed or deleted until the package catalog is repaired..."
I click repair but it fails.

running sudo apt-get update fails
this is the error report:

```
"W: Failed to fetch archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_main_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead."
```

Content of source.list:

```
# deb cdrom:[Lubuntu 12.04 _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20120423)]/ precise main multiverse restricted universe

# See help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.


## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates restricted main multiverse universe
deb-src extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main"
```

I tried:
reading other answers of the likes and doing what they suggested:

1.
changing the server i use

2.

```
    sudo apt-get autoclean
    sudo apt-get autoremove
    sudo apt-get -f install
```

3.
the following didn't work either:

```
    cd /var/lib/apt
    sudo mv lists lists.old
    sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
```

Help me askubuntu, your my only hope!
Thanks again

Comment: you can try to rebuild your sources.list file from this [website](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) make sure you dont select gnome ppa while building the list from this site

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Failed to fetch" while updating](http://askubuntu.com/questions/214327/failed-to-fetch-while-updating)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)