# Error when running update: Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, software-sources

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS through bootable USB. When I try to update Ubuntu using the command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I am getting the below errors. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

```
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages [8,875 B]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages [107 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [3,681 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en              
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en [1,679 B]
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en [2,266 B]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en [60.2 kB]
Fetched 602 kB in 1min 14s (8,099 B/s)                                         
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release
     Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file
     (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Sources.list:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse


## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Failed to fetch" while updating](http://askubuntu.com/questions/214327/failed-to-fetch-while-updating)

Comment: similar old question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/545260/updating-problem .

Comment: @karel  No, I have tried those things earlier, but no luck. I have installed the ubuntu newly but again I am facing this problem. You can see my question here http://askubuntu.com/questions/634010/ubuntu-14-04-02-descktop-failed-to-update-packages.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: FYI: The entry exists: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  – ` 74b86826be17320e48b75d9d147dea85            22871 restricted/source/Sources`

Comment: @Pilot6 I have edited /etc/apt/sources.list. Could you please check it once .

Comment: @Pilot6 even if I install something its throwing broken packages first  fix it.

Answer (score 1):

restricted/source/Sources is actually missing on server side
Try this (use sources.gz instead):

`sudo apt-get -o Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order::=gz update`

if it solves the issue alter apt.conf and add/alter line

`    Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order { "gz"; "bz2"; };

Comment: I have tried that one I am getting `W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

Comment: I have tried different mirrors but no luck.