# sudo apt update gives error mesages

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, raspberrypi, arm64

When I try and run the command `sudo apt update` it shows this error message

```
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/groovy/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/groovy-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/groovy-backports/universe/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Why is apt showing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Failed to fetch" while updating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214327/failed-to-fetch-while-updating)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I have updated my computer since and it is fixed